# how to invoke a function taking more arguments than the mock-method from within a call-expectation

Tags: googlemock

I have a Problem utilizing google mock doing a dedicated verification.

Let's say, I have mock'd a function like this:

```
MOCK_METHOD1( FuncName, void( ClassType const& ) );
```

(don't care about the mock declaration itself)

I want to place expectations towards FuncName, the way invoking
a Function, that verifies the instance of ClassType to be valid considering *additional* arguments:

```
bool const VerifyIntegrity( ClassType const& Obj, int const& param1, int const& param2 )
{
   if( param1 == Obj.member1 && param2 == Obj.member2 ) return true;
   return false;
}
```

This actually is pseudo-code and the real implementation utilizes templates (deducible) and enumerations, but the example should be sufficient.
So, how can I invoke VerifyItegrity(...) within a call expectation?

```
EXPECT_CALL( Mock, FuncName( _ ) ).WillOnce( ...???? );
```

Basically, the question is how can I explicitly select an argument within a call-expectation and use it by an invocation of an *arbitrary* function (signature).

What I don't want to do is writing a comparison-operato (no need up to now) and creating matching reference objects as they are too many in numbers (permutations).

Thanks in advance- all Replies are appreciated! :)

Comment: Would a custom matcher work for your case?  See https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Defining_Matchers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193990/how-to-compare-special-fields-in-google-mock

Comment: If VerifyIntegrity is really that simple, the google mock way of doing it is writing a matcher expression instead of that function: `AllOf(Field(&ClassType::member1, ...), Field(&ClassType::member2, ...))`, which has the advantage of Google Mock being able to spell out what field values were expected vs. what values were found.

Comment: @RA: Thanks for the response. I thought about using a self-written action but struggling with passing (selecting) arguments (see comment to the answer below). Is there something like selecting arguments from the Mocking method inside a call expectation? `EXPECT_CALL( Mock, Method( _,_,_ ).WillOnce( CustomAction( arg0, 2.0, "hello" ));` whereas arg0 ist argetting the zeroth argument? And if sow how _exactly_ do I have to use it? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your comment to RA, I think you really want to use custom actions, so I rewrote the answer completely. I left the original answer (about fixing arguments at expectation time) intact, as it might be helpful for other people, too. Custom actions allow you to create function objects with Google Mock means instead of declaring them by hand, using `std::bind` or lambdas. Use it like this:

At the top level (not inside a TEST or fixture class)

```
ACTION_P2(VerifyIntegrity, param1, param2)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(param1, arg0.member1);
    EXPECT_EQ(param2, arg0.member2);
}
```

Then you expect the call using

```
EXPECT_CALL(Mock, FuncName(_)).
      WillOnce(VerifyIntegrity(2.0, "hello"));
```

The parameters of the mocked function (in this case `FuncName` are passed as `arg0`, `arg1` and so on into the code block you wrote in ACTION_P2. Behind you back, ACTION_P2 is surely a macro that defines a template class that has a template member function, so `arg0` to `argN` have the types of the mock function parameters (likely always as reference), while the type of `param1` and `param2` is deduced from the constants `2.0` and `"hello"` you write in the EXPECT_CALL clause.

---

If C++11 is available, you can use `std::bind` to fix the arguments:

```
using testing::Truly;
using namespace std::placeholders;
EXPECT_CALL(Mock, FuncName(Truly(std::bind(VerifyIntegrity, _1, 0, 100))));
```

Another way, if VerifyIntegrity is really as simple as you make it in your question is not using a function like that, but coding this verification in the Google Mock matcher language:

```
using ::testing::AllOf;
using ::testing::Field;
EXPECT_CALL(Mock, FuncName(AllOf(
                    Field(&ClassType::member1, 0),
                    Field(&ClassType::member2, 9))));
```

It has the advantage of Google Mock being able to spell out what field values were expected vs. what values were found. in these two fields.

Comment: Up to now I did not use std::bind and i'm afraid mixing up problems when combining google mock and std::bind. Your 2nd suggestion is not applicable since I have to call methods and using gmock's Property can be used for methods without arguments only. I was thinking on writing an action taking n arguments but I am somehow lost in the syntax: how can I call the action with an argument that comes from the mocking method? Specifically, how can I address some arguments form Mockmethod(_,_,_,_) and forward them? Is there something like arg0, arg1 to select the passed arguments to forwarding? Thx!

Comment: I consider the methodology of using std::bind currently most suitable. Specifically to select an Argument and forward it. Unfortunately, the `Truly(...)` Statement expands to a large evaluation logic which will trigger a compiler warning considering decoration name length (no major issue). Furthermore, if the expectation fails, it practically is impossible to find the root cause of the 'mismatch' from the description. Using a self written matcher also does the job, but visually separates the verification from the call expectation. I will evolve my solution a little bit more and come back here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something in your use case here, RA's suggestion of using a custom matcher will do exactly what you want. For example:

```
MATCHER_P2(ClassTypeMatches, m1, m2, "") {

    return arg.member1 == m1 && arg.member2 == m2;
}

TEST(StackOverflow, CustomMatcher) {

    MockThing thing;
    EXPECT_CALL(thing, FuncName(ClassTypeMatches(1, 2)));

    ClassType ct;
    ct.member1 = 1;
    ct.member2 = 2;
    thing.FuncName(ct);
}
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, please provide a few more specifics for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: A custom matcher will do the job, but placing expectations inside the custom matcher seems better to me than utilizing a construct with assigning values from within the unit test. But still, is there a mechanism inside google mock which let you select an arbitrary argument from within a mock'd call and invoke a custom action with arbitrary arguments? Or is only std::bind capable of doing so?

Comment: If you don't want to use std::bind, you could simply invoke your `VerifyIntegrity()` method from within the custom matcher or action. Would that give you the behavior you want?

Comment: From what I learned up to now, there seems no _alternative_ to use std::bind in some context. The root problem is, that you normally can invoke actions only which match the mock's method signature _exactly_. If you have an arbitrary function you want to call, there seems not to be a way to call it with yet existing gmock-methodology. So the calling convention could looke like: `EXPECT_CALL( Mock, Method( _ ) ).WillOnce( WithArg<0>(Invoke(std::bind(ArbitraryFunc, _1, nSpecialArg, "Hello"))));` I'm not sure if WithArg<> is yet necessary.

Comment: You were shown how to avoid using std::bind for matchers and action using user-defined custom actions. So this definitely is an alternative to using std::bind. Furthermore you don't need to use std::bind if you just need to reorder and select arguments passed to the mocked method, because WithArg can do that. In this case, WithArg adapts a function that does *not* match exactly to the mocked signature. You only need std::bind if you need to provide data from the expectation as argument *and* do not want to use a custom action.

Comment: And yes, in that case WithArg<0> is not necessary, because the result of std::bind can be called with any number of arguments that is at least as high as the highest numbered placeholder.